# How to Create a VIEW in oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle19c

So I'm supposed to create a view **product_view** that presents the information about how many products of a particular type are in each warehouse: product ID, product name, category_id,  warehouse id, total quantity on hand for this warehouse.

So I used this query and tried to change it so many times but I keep getting errors

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW PRODUCT_VIEW AS
 SELECT p.product_id, p.product_name,
 COUNT(p.product_id), SUM(i.quantity_on_hand)
 FROM oe.product_information p JOIN oe.inventories i
 ON p.product_id=i.product_id
 ORDER BY i.warehouse_id;
```

ERROR at line 2:
ORA-00928: missing SELECT keyword

Please help... Thanks

[Image showing the Tables in the OE schema](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nxxid.png)
[Image showing the error that occurs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZDx14.png)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: yes, it's allowed, but I avoid it. You can easily order the output of the view with SELECT * FROM product_view ORDER BY whatever. This is more flexible...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I get errors creating a view, I firstly drop the `CREATE ... AS` line and fix the query until it works. Then you need to name all the columns, for instance `COUNT(p.product_id)` won't work, you'll need to write something like `COUNT(p.product_id) AS product_count` or specify a list of aliases, like [so](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/CREATE-VIEW.html#GUID-61D2D2B4-DACC-4C7C-89EB-7E50D9594D30)

I'm not sure what the output of your query should look like. You'll get better answers quicker on stackexchange if you type a minimal example including the CREATE statments, some input data and your desired output, leaving out columns that are not essential.